# Redux State changes but not re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to delete a card from my list. The state in Redux Dev Tools is updated, but the UI is not re rendered.Not sure why?

Does this reducer logic mutate my existing state?

Tried checking using componentWillReceiveProps , noticed in deleting the card, the newProps is not changed.

**In Reducer**

```
    const listReducerDefaultState = [
  {
    title: "title",
    id: `list0`,
    cards: [
      {
        id: `card0`,
        title: "card 1"
      },
      {
        id: `card1`,
        title: "card 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "title",
    id: `list1`,
    cards: [
      {
        id: `card2`,
        title: "card 1"
      },
      {
        id: `card=3`,
        title: "card 2"
      },
      {
        id: `card=4`,
        title: "card 3"
      },
      {
        id: `card=5`,
        title: "card 4"
      }
    ]
  }
];

.... 

case "DELETE_CARD": {
      const { ListID } = action.payload;
      const CardID = action.payload.id;
      let newState = state;

      let index = newState.findIndex(item => item.id === action.payload.ListID);
      newState[index].cards = newState[index].cards.filter(
        ({ id }) => id !== CardID
      );
      // console.log(newState);
      return newState;
    }
```

**Action**

```
export const deleteCard = ({ id, ListID }) => ({
  type: "DELETE_CARD",
  payload: { id, ListID }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let newState = state;
```

is the culprit.
This is mutating the original state.
All logic in reducer should be immutable.

try using this:

```
const newState = {...state};
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)
will you accept my answer and upvote it? @MonicaAcha

Comment: This will only make a "shallow" copy of the array and the objects themselves will still be identical and be mutated. This could cause issues. It's not a good idea to ever mutate Redux state because it can result in very subtle bugs and things not re-rendering properly. I would recommend also making copies of all the other values before changing them as well.

Comment: @skovy - any relavent article ?

Comment: right, it is necessary to use `immutable` Map and Lists inside of the redux state
@skovy @MonicaAcha

Comment: There is a lot of great details in the Redux docs: https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data#why-is-immutability-required-by-redux

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
case "DELETE_CARD":
  {
    const {
      ListID,
      id: CardID
    } = action.payload;

    return state.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === ListID) {
        return ({
          ...item,
          cards: item.cards.filter(({ id }) => id !== cardID)
        })
      }

      return item;
    });
```

to avoid mutating the state.